# how to retrieve data from sql table and insert it into another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a 'online students discussion platform' for a certain university, i want a student to post a question to only students belonging in the same faculty so that if ICT student posts a question, the system extracts all the students in ICT faculty from the students table, attaches them to the post and inserts them into the table receivers.

The system is extracting all students from the students table but it is inserting only one student in the table receivers.

TABLES:

```
-students(regno,name,faculty_code) PRIMARY KEY regn
-receivers(id, regno,message_id)
```

how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: Apart from your missing code: This design sounds a lot like you want to copy a lot of data for every single post. Just add the relevant groups to a post and let this define visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a table for receivers, a better approach would be for you to have a "faculty_code" field in the "message" table which would be populated with the faculty_code of the poster. So for each student, extract messages where student.faculty_code is equal to message.faculty_code.

That way a student only sees messages posted by students in the same faculty as him/her.